# Firebase Analytics Disable Audience Country Tracking

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I'm working on an application where location tracking is strictly not allowed. I want to use Firebase Analytic's other features like PageTransitions and Crashalitics, but if I cannot disable the Audience location tracking, I cannot use any of it. Is this something I disable in the AndroidManifest and Info.plist files? Or something I disable in the console? Is it possible to disable just this one feature of Firebase Analytics?

I'm using flutter with firebase dependencies:

```
  firebase_auth: 0.8.4+2
  cloud_firestore: 0.9.13+1
  firebase_analytics: 2.1.1+2
```

I've disabled Ad ID tracking in Android, but in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics) it looks like it is not possible to disable this for iOS?

Comment: Firebase Analytics' location information is derived from the IP address that the device reports. As far as I know it is *not* using the device's built-in location information.

Comment: Even if it is only using IP address information, I'd still like to be able to opt-out of tracking that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to disable the geography information. Analytics uses IP addresses to derive the geolocation of a visitor. Customers may apply [IP masking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2905384/) so that Google Analytics uses only a portion of an IP address collected, rather than the entire address. In addition, customers can override IPs at will using their [IP Override](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uip) feature.

Sources:
[Analytics Help: Safeguarding your data](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6004245?utm_id=ad), 
[Data Collection: Google Analytics for Firebase data collection](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318039), [Automatically collected user properties](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en), [Google Analytics for Firebase Use Policy](https://firebase.google.com/policies/analytics)