# Change default data collected by Firebase/Google analytics

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

We use Firebase/Google analytics in our android app. Each event is saved with a lot of extra information (user-id, device-info, timestamps, user-properties, geographical location …). The extra info is there by default but we don’t want it to be collected.

We tried 2 things:

**1) Update Big Query Schema**

Delete the unwanted columns from Big Query. Unfortunately, Big Query creates a new export every day. So we would need to know where those fields are coming from. Something we don't know.

**2) DefaultParameters within the app**

Tried to use default parameters from inside the app, so the city will always be null. Here is an example with the user’s city

```
Bundle defaultValues = new Bundle();
defaultValues.putString("geo.city", null);
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(ctx).setDefaultEventParameters(defaultValues);
```

Unfortunately, we still see `geo.city` in our BigQuery data filled in.

Is there a way of changing what is collected by default?

Comment: In Flurry, by contrast, a simple `FlurryAgent.setReportLocation(false) ` is sufficient.

Comment: Take a look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56942636/4878977

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to disable the geography information. Analytics uses IP addresses to derive the geolocation of a visitor. Probably the solution about update Big Query Schema is a viable way. You have to create a system that carries out this update on a daily basis precisely because the export takes place every day.

Comment: How can we create such a system? In the Google cloud console? Do we need to upgrade our account?

Comment: You can do this with the system you want, it is about updating the values ​​of the tables once they are written.

Comment: I see what you mean. The downside is that, should the update/delete fail for some reason, the data will be present. That by itself is already a deal breaker for our regulatory team.

Comment: Everything is based on making the system solid, perhaps with other control scripts where, for example, if they detect a value other than null (or from a placeholder you have defined with which you replace the original value) they make the update run again. If you start everything for example every 5 minutes (on the data of the new day so as not to burden the system) and an e-mail notification when the update is really done, you should succeed in the inside. 0-risk solutions do not exist in general, there are good management and internal policy regulations.

Comment: Seems like you're right :(. No way to turn off location tracking... 
Which means bye-bye firebase